# What is Geometric complexity theory (GCT)?

Tags: complexity-theory

I was reading about complexity theory and I got a term Geometric complexity theory. I google the term on internet and find out that

> **Geometric complexity theory (GCT)**, is a research program in computational complexity theory proposed by Ketan Mulmuley and Milind Sohoni. The goal of the program is to answer the most famous open problem in computer science – whether P = NP – by showing that the complexity class P is not equal to the complexity class NP---- from wikipedia

**Question :**  How researcher in this area prove or disprove that P = NP ? ( A high level explanation is sufficient)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_complexity_theory) is a good place to start.

Comment: The current goal of the field is to separate VP and VNP. You can check out Josh Grochow's answer on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17610/wikipedia-style-explanation-of-geometric-complexity-theory/17629#17629.